# Solving for n in the equation

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

I found an equation like this

$$5^2 \times 5^4 \times 5^6 \times 5^8 \times \cdots \times 5^{2n} = (0.008)^{-30}$$

Can someone explain me how to find the value of n in this equation.. I tried but couldn't get any result after sometime..

Comment: Could you include what you tried specifically? As a hint, you can express the right hand side as $5^{-90}$.

Comment: @Harry I believe you mean the right hand side is $5^{90}$, since $$(0.08)^{-30}=\left(\frac{1}{125}\right)^{-30}=(5^{-3})^{-30}=5^{-3\times -30}=5^{90}$$

Comment: @Dave you're absolutely right. A silly mistake.

Comment: Yes...after putting right hand side as 5^90, and writing the left hand side as 5^n(n+1) , I was able to solve the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the equation is equivalent to 
$$5^2\times 5^4\times5^6\times\cdots\times5^{2n}=5^{90}$$
Combining the bases we have:
$$5^x=5^{90}$$
where
$$x=2\sum_{k=1}^nk=2\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)=n(n+1)$$
I'll let you take it from here.